# Contradiction between complex baseband and real-valued baseband

Tags: modulation, demodulation, quadrature

Suppose a direct-conversion transmitter+receiver (ideal transmitter) along with its filters. In complex baseband, the filters in the signal chain can be modeled as a complex-valued FIR filter ($y$, $c$, $x$ are complex-valued!):

$$
y = \sum_{k=0}^K c_k x[n-k]
$$

Rewriting this in cartesian coordinates gives:

$$
y_i + j y_q = \underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^K \left(a_k x_i[n-k] - b_k x_q[n-k]\right)}_{y_i} + j \sum_{k=0}^K \left( b_k x_i[n-k] + a_k x_q[n-k] \right)
$$

Now only considering the real part, it can be seen that it consists of **two different filters** with which the real and imaginary input signals are filtered.

Now consider the same system from a practical perspective: After the DAC and upconversion, the RF signal looks as follows:

$$
x_{rf} = x_i \cos \omega_c t + x_q \sin \omega_c t
$$

The output sequence $y_i$ is obtained by multiplying $x_{rf}$ with $\cos(\omega_c t +\phi)$ and filtering it with a filter called $H$:

$$
y_i = H( x_{rf} \cos(\omega_c t +\phi) ) \\
\approx H(x_i/2 \cos\phi + x_q/2 \sin\phi) \\
= \frac{\cos\phi}{2} H(x_i + x_q \tan\phi)
= G(x_i + x_q \tan\phi)
$$

The filter $H$ (or $G$) is modeled as a FIR filter:

$$
y_i = \sum_{k=0}^K \left( g_k x_i[n-k] + g_k \tan\phi x_q [n-k] \right)
$$

From the equation above it can be seen that the real and imaginary part are **filtered through only one filter** (they differ just by the constant $\tan\phi$ !).

Where does this contradiction come from?

PS: I know that the first approach is the correct one because it gives the correct results. I do not understand why it is not consistent with my second approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after studying for hours I will attempt an answer to my own question. It does make sense now but I hope that it is correct.

Let us start with the second form:

$$
y_i = \sum_{k=0}^K \left( g_k x_i[n-k] + g_k \tan\phi x_q[n-k] \right) = \sum_{k=0}^K \left( a_{i,k} x_i[n-k] + b_{i,k} x_q[n-k] \right)
$$

Yes, from this is evident that $a_{i,k}=\beta b_{i,k}$, i.e. the i-output is a linear combination of the two I/Q inputs. This however, **falls apart as soon as there is any filter in the RF path**. Let us consider the a filter $h$ at RF:

$$
y_{rf} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x_{rf}(\tau) h(t-\tau)d\tau
$$

Since the input signal has bandpass characteristics (from which the definition of complex baseband arises) it also has the following canonical representation:

$$
h_c(t) = 2 h_i(t) \cos\omega_c t +2 h_q(t)\sin\omega_c t \\
= 2\mathrm{Re}\left\{ h_z(t) exp(j\omega t) \right\} 
$$

and

$$
h_z(t) = h_i(t) + j h_q(t)
$$

From this is is clear that I and Q parts are filtered with two different filters and hence the i-output is **not** a linear combination of the inputs any more.

Back to the first form: Indeed, solving only for the I channel gives $2K$ real valued coefficients, in the general case!

Solving for the Q channel gives again $2K$ coefficients ($4K$ in total). However, if I and Q are perfectly balanced, the coefficients obtained from the I channel and the Q channel will be identical. So there are really only $2K$ real-valued or $K$ complex valued coefficients, as expected.

However, if there is an I/Q imbalance, the input/output relationship can still be faithfully described but now in general all $4K$ real-valued coefficients are required!

Interestingly, the difference between the coefficients obtained from the I channel and the Q channel corresponds to the (frequency dependent) I/Q imbalance.

Answer (score 1):

As a sidenote:

When you demodulate your signal $x_{\mathrm{rf}}(t)$  you say that there is some phase difference $\phi$. This translates to [crosstalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crosstalk) (i.e., the quadrature and in-phase components influence each other at the receiver). It's easy to see that if $\phi = 0$ (namely, we know exactly when to sample the received signal), there is no crosstalk at all:

$$y_i = \sum_{k=0}^K \left( g_k x_i[n-k] + g_k \tan(0) x_q [n-k] \right) =  \sum_{k=0}^K  g_k x_i[n-k]$$

In the baseband domain, this means that the filter $c_k$ is purely real (if it was purely imaginary, then there wouldn't be crosstalk either, you just have to invert the channels to retrieve the information correctly).

The answer:

Whether there is crosstalk or not, both of your equations get to the same result, but with different names. Using your notation, $a_k$ in the first equation would be equivalent to $g_k$ in the second one, and $b_k$ to $-g_k\tan(\phi)$. I believe that your confusion arose from thinking of $a_k$ and $b_k$ as two different filters (which is correct), instead of thinking of them as the real and imaginary part of a single filter ($c_k$).

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. However, my point is: In the second case ($a_k=g_k$ and $b_k=-g_k \tan\phi$) the coefficients are NOT arbitrary, there is a relationship $b_k = \beta a_k$. In the first case $a_k$ and $b_k$ are arbitrary. In subsequent SIMULINK simulations I have seen that in absence of any RF filters both are indeed equivalent. But as soon as I add a bandpass filter **at RF**, $y_i$ **cannot** be described as linear combination of $x_i$ and $x_q$ any more! It requires that $a_k \neq \beta b_k$ (i.e., both branches have **different** filters). Why is this the case?

Comment: @divB I'm not sure I understand your problem, but it's probably my fault and not yours. Maybe a simulation diagram showing what you meant in the comment would help.